# Unable to access via https on safari browser

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, codeigniter-3

We have used code in htaccess to force redirect `http` to `https`. It seems to work fine for Chrome and Mozilla however it does not seem to be working on Safari, in MacOS. We are doing our project in PHP (Framework: CodeIgnitor). The web server is apache and the `htaccess` file on that respective project directory is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I hope there is a certificate on the server?

Comment: Which behavior are you observing in Safari?

Comment: https://www.example.com this url not working in Safari but is working on Chrome and Mozilla

Comment: None of these rules would care about which browser you're using. Define "not working", please. Do you get an error?